# How to dynamically set a checkbox's ID attribute in a jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a DataTables table populated with JSON data returned from a Java servlet. Each row in the table has a checkbox. I have code that can add a check to every checkbox but I need to figure out how to evaluate the value of a specific field in the JSON and, if the criteria is met, check the box. I'm open to any way that will work. So far I have been trying to set each checkbox's ID attribute when the table is instantiated. The idea is that my code would look at the ID value of every checkbox and check only those that equal a specific value. I would like to know if it's possible to set the ID attribute equal to the value of a specific field in the JSON. An abbreviated version of the JSON looks like this. Note that it contains a "status" field. I'd like to set the ID equal to the status value.

```js
{"data":[{"date":"20180101","status":"Incomplete","total_files":22,"total_size":16896},{"date":"20180102","status":"Complete","total_files":24,"total_size":19968,"itws":"itws","itws_count":24,"itws_status":"Complete"}]}
```

Here is a snippet of my DataTables instantiation code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                var table = $('#search_results').DataTable({
                        searching: false,
                        paging: false,
                    "ajax": {
                        url: "http://localhost:8080/FileSearch-1/FileSearch"+servletUrl+"&startDate="+startDateVal+"&endDate="+endDateVal+"&startTime="+startTimeVal+"&endTime="+endTimeVal,
                        method: "GET",
                        xhrFields: {
                            withCredentials: true
                        }  
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        {
                        "className": "details-control",
                        "orderable": "false",
                        "data": "null",
                        "defaultContent": '', 
                        "render": function () {
                            return '<i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                        },
                        "width":"15px"
                        },
                        { "render": function () {
                                return '<input type="checkbox" id="status" name="oneDay">';
                            }
                        },
                        { "data": "date" },
                        { "data": "status" },
                        { "data": "total_files" },
                        { "data": "total_size" }
                    ],
                    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
                });
```

Is it possible to set the checkbox's ID attribute to the value of the status field in the JSON? For example, if the status field is "Complete" then the checkbox's ID would be set to "Complete." 
I've tried doing things like

```js
return '<input type="checkbox" id="'+status+'" name="oneDay">';
```

...in which case the table will render correctly but the value of ID will remain blank.

```js
return '<input type="checkbox" id="'+data:status+'" name="oneDay">';
```

...in which case it won't render at all and produces a JavaScript error that states the : is an unexpected token.

Comment: An `id` is an identification... That **has to be unique** like your driver's licence id number. It **not** the place to dynamically set a value. Use a [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) attribute instead. -- Furthermore, [datatables](https://datatables.net/) creates dynamical elements on each [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()). You just can't modify DOM elements like this when an intance is active on them.

Comment: Voting to close as *"too broad"*. Basic reading of the plugin documentation should be done.

Comment: @Louys Good point about using .data() instead of the Id, I will include that going forward. However, it doesn't address the question which is actually not too broad but pretty specific. After more elbow grease I figured it out. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The value of an element's attribute, whether it's the name, Id, or a custom data attribute can indeed be set to the value of an element in the JSON. Here is how I did it. 
Here is my old code.

```js
"render": function () {
                            return '<i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                        },
```

The new code includes two changes. There is a new line above the line that creates the checkbox. And the syntax to set the value of the attribute has been changed.

```js
data: 'status',
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                                return '<input type="checkbox" data-status="'+data+'" id="'+data+'" name="oneDay">';
                            }
```

I added the "data-status" attribute per Louy's suggestion and will try to use that in lieu of the Id attribute going forward. The result of the new code is that the value of the Id and data-status attributes get set to the value of the "status" field in the JSON.